# Googlebot & AWS Cloudfront/S3 - Getting a bunch of 403s

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront, googlebot

I'm hosting [my website](http://www.pristineclean.com.au) on AWS through S3 with Cloudfront. I've noticed that Googlebot and also [Apex Ping](http://apex.sh/ping/) detect 403 errors when accessing my website. When I access it myself I don't see any 4xx or any 5xx errors in the network tab with Chrome Developer Tools enabled. I'm wondering what might be causing it.

My suspicion is that it may be a Cloudfront configuration. Specifically I've enabled `Custom SSL Certificate` and am using an AWS generated certificate (ACM). With this option I'm forced to use the `Only Clients that Support Server Name Indication (SNI)` configuration. Is this potentially causing the breakage? My understanding is that Googlebot supports SNI as per this [post](https://community.qualys.com/thread/14485) so I'm a bit perplexed as to what might be causing the 403s.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your website is currently giving me the following error:

> ERROR
>
> The request could not be satisfied.
>
> The Amazon CloudFront distribution is configured to block access from your country.
> Generated by cloudfront (CloudFront)
> Request ID: 5i6brNX28KLeWWp8CJ6oSLv96aggZCxlSsMtc6gvZ3I8STS3mtmS9g==

Googlebot and Apex Ping are probably seeing the same response.

So the problem may be that you need to open up more countries in your configuration. This is done on the "Geo-Restriction Settings" page. If your website doesn't need to be Geo Restricted, then don't: set "Enable Geo-Restriction" to "No".

Comment: Thanks. I'll remove the Geo-restrictions. I did have a whitelist for Australia only. If that solves my issue I'll mark your answer as the accepted solution.

Comment: Looks like the geo-restriction was the cause of the 403s. Thanks!